# Has anyone used UDS (Unified Development Server) on a clustered system?

Tags: cluster-computing

UDS (formerly known as Forte 4GL) is the platform our current system is running on. I remember finding a flag in a forum that documented how to deploy this on a Veritas cluster. However, now that we have modern hardware coming in, I can't find that note anywhere in Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it (after hours of searching) at http://sundusum.com/gpunkt/knowledgebase/articles/7240.html

"To allow for configurations like clustered environments, a test for a
new environment variable, FORTE_CM_NO_CANONICAL_NAMECHK, was added in
Forte release 3M.  If that environment variable is set, the check for
the match between FORTE_NS_ADDRESS and the machine name is skipped.

"The FORTE_CM_NO_CANONICAL_NAMECHK can be set in the fortedef files on
machines where running the environment manager is allowed.  Setting that
environment variable on all nodes should be avoided, since that would
allow the environment manager to be started on any node which can lead
to problems that canonical name check is designed to prevent."

Comment: The site is gone, so good thing the info was transferred here (not that I need it anymore).